# Multiple Overloading of Operators

Tags: c++, overloading

as you can see from the code I want to overload the < operator twice. 1 to sort by dist and the other by nodeID. I would like to check if there is any way to call the different overloaded methods. For example in the compLoc method, when I use the sort() method I want it to be sorted by nodeID but in other methods I want it to be sorted by dist.

```
struct AttSet{
int nodeID;
double dist;

bool operator < (const AttSet & str) const{
    return (dist < str.dist);
}
/*
bool operator <(const AttSet & str){
    return (nodeID < str.nodeID);
*/
bool operator == (const AttSet & str){
    return nodeID == str.nodeID;
}};

void compLoc(Edge *edge, vector<Node*> &vertices){
int l = edge->length;
int vl = edge->head->nodeID;
int vr = edge->tail->nodeID;
/*
sort(vertices[vl]->attSet.begin(), vertices[vl]->attSet.end());
sort(vertices[vr]->attSet.begin(), vertices[vr]->attSet.end());
vector<AttSet> vInterSec;
set_intersection(vertices[vl]->attSet.begin(), vertices[vl]->attSet.end(), vertices[vr]->attSet.begin(), vertices[vr]->attSet.end(), back_inserter(vInterSec));
*/}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can implement this by using functor and take the comparator(operator< overload) outside the AttSet.
Here is a simple example:

```
struct AtrComparator {
     bool distcmp;
     AttrComparator(bool distcmp): distcmp(distcmp) {}
     bool operator() (const AttSet &s1, const AttSet &s2) {
          if(distcmp) {
               return s1.dist < s2.dist;
          } else {
               return s1.nodeID < s2.nodeID;
          }
     }
}
```

And then you can do the sort through different feed, dist or nodeID. 
.e.g:

```
sort(vertices[vl]->attSet.begin(), vertices[vl]->attSet.end(), AttComparator(true));
sort(vertices[vl]->attSet.begin(), vertices[vl]->attSet.end(), AttComparator(false));
```

Answer (score 4):

You cannot have overloads that have the same signature. This holds for any function. How would you try to decide which version to use?

If you want sort the object based on different criteria you should use the [`sort`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort) version that takes  a custom comparer function as the third argument.

Edit:
Of course you need to provide the comparer. I would suggest providing the comparers as static functions of the class if you have such power. This way you will not pollute enclosing namespace and you can access privates of the class with out exposing any getters. Since your properties are public the lambda would suffice, and probably be the best/cleanest approach.

Feeling adventurous I made a simple c++11 exercise program. For what it's worth, if you ever decided to go for proper encapsulation, I've shown both approaches:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
#include <initializer_list>
#include <cassert>
using namespace std;

template<typename T>
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, const std::vector<T>& v){
    for(const auto& el : v){
        out << el << '\n';
    }
    return out;
}

class A {
    int a;
    int b;
public:
    A(std::initializer_list<int> l){
        assert(l.size() == 2);
        auto i = l.begin();
        a = *i;
        ++i;
        b = *i;
    }

    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& stream, const A& e){
        return stream << e.a << ' ' << e.b;
    }

    static bool compareViaA(const A& lhs, const A& rhs){
        return rhs.a > lhs.a;
    }

    static bool compareViaB(const A& lhs, const A& rhs){
        return rhs.b > lhs.b;
    }
};

int main() {
    std::vector<A> v {{2,3}, {3,2}, {1,4}, {4,1}};
    //sort(v.begin(), v.end(), [](const A& a, const A& b){return a.a > b.a;}) // fails because of privacy violation
    sort(v.begin(), v.end(), A::compareViaA);
    std::cout << v << '\n';
    sort(v.begin(), v.end(), A::compareViaB);
    std::cout << v << '\n';
    return 0;
}
```

Live: http://ideone.com/lDMujx.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do that. They have the same signature exactly.

Use a functor or a lambda and pass it to whatever algorithm you want.

```
std::sort(std::begin(container), std::end(container),
    [](const element_type& lhs, const element_type& rhs) { return ...; });
```

Another way to do this:

```
struct compare_by_node_id {
    bool operator()(const AttSet& lhs, const AttSet& rhs) const {
        return lhs.nodeID < rhs.nodeID;
    }
};

struct compare_by_dist {
    bool operator()(const AttSet& lhs, const AttSet& rhs) const {
        return lhs.dist < rhs.dist;
    }
};
```

And you could pass that to the algorithm like:

```
std::sort(std::begin(container), std::end(container), compare_by_node_id());
```

Answer (score 0):

you cannot do that because compiler doesn't see difference between:

```
bool operator < (const AttSet & str) const; //this const doesn't allow to override any property of object(instance of AttSet) if I remember
```

and

```
bool operator < (const AttSet & str);
```

there're the same same return type, same parameter (same signature)

compiler cannot choose which one is better

Answer (score 0):

There's not a great way to do this as far as I am aware, since the compiler will see these as the exact same and will throw an error. If you need to do this, use the `<` operator as whatever will occur the most often, and then write a method that you can call to compare two object. Something like this:

> ```
> bool operator< (const Blah &blah) const {
>     return (most often operation)
> }
>
> bool Blah::other_operation(const Blah &blah) const {
>     return (other operation)
> }
> ```